# What are the possible values of KbChannel field on SearchActivity standard Object?

Tags: knowledge, search, searchactivity

What are the possible values of `KbChannel` field on `SearchActivity` standard Object?

I am trying to understand better SearchActivity standard Object, however, Object Reference Guide doesn't list this object https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference, the index goes from `ScratchOrgInfo` to `SearchPromotionRule` skipping `SearchActivity`

[image]

also Field Reference Guide doesn't list this object as well
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference.htm, the index goes from `ScorecardShare` to `SearchPromotionRule`  skipping `SearchActivity` as well.

[image]

This document
https://www.datasert.com/products/realfire/release-notes/object-details-report-sample#sobject-SearchActivity

mentions that KbChannel is a Picklist field with 5 values but doesn't specify the values.

When I perform query `SELECT Id, KbChannel,ClickRank,ClickedRecordId, QueryDate,Period FROM SearchActivity` I can see the only value of this picklist.

[image]
How can I get all the values and understand which channels does this object support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use Workbench tool to run Sobject Describe endpoint

https://workbench.developerforce.com/restExplorer.php?url=/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/SearchActivity/describe&autoExec=1

which provides information about five possible picklist values of this field.

[image]

Which include

- All Channels(`AllChannels`) - assuming this is an aggregate option.
- Internal App (`App`) - assuming this value corresponds to internal
  Knowledge search activity for users having Salesforce or Salesforce
  Platform licenses
- Public Knowledge Base (`Pkb`) - assuming this value
  corresponds to public site guest user profiles
- Customer(`Csp`) - assuming this value corresponds to the Experience Cloud Customer portal users which have Community and Community Plus licenses
- Partner (`Prm`) - assuming this value corresponds to the Experience Cloud
  Partner portal users which have Partner user licenses

The full json response I have put here https://gist.github.com/bdovh/e1d0a326964caad4108e378d23c0dcb1

and this is field describe extract only below

```
 {
    "aggregatable" : true,
    "aiPredictionField" : false,
    "autoNumber" : false,
    "byteLength" : 765,
    "calculated" : false,
    "calculatedFormula" : null,
    "cascadeDelete" : false,
    "caseSensitive" : false,
    "compoundFieldName" : null,
    "controllerName" : null,
    "createable" : false,
    "custom" : false,
    "defaultValue" : null,
    "defaultValueFormula" : null,
    "defaultedOnCreate" : false,
    "dependentPicklist" : false,
    "deprecatedAndHidden" : false,
    "digits" : 0,
    "displayLocationInDecimal" : false,
    "encrypted" : false,
    "externalId" : false,
    "extraTypeInfo" : null,
    "filterable" : true,
    "filteredLookupInfo" : null,
    "formulaTreatNullNumberAsZero" : false,
    "groupable" : true,
    "highScaleNumber" : false,
    "htmlFormatted" : false,
    "idLookup" : false,
    "inlineHelpText" : null,
    "label" : "Channel",
    "length" : 255,
    "mask" : null,
    "maskType" : null,
    "name" : "KbChannel",
    "nameField" : false,
    "namePointing" : false,
    "nillable" : false,
    "permissionable" : false,
    "picklistValues" : [ {
      "active" : true,
      "defaultValue" : false,
      "label" : "All Channels",
      "validFor" : null,
      "value" : "AllChannels"
    }, {
      "active" : true,
      "defaultValue" : false,
      "label" : "Internal App",
      "validFor" : null,
      "value" : "App"
    }, {
      "active" : true,
      "defaultValue" : false,
      "label" : "Public Knowledge Base",
      "validFor" : null,
      "value" : "Pkb"
    }, {
      "active" : true,
      "defaultValue" : false,
      "label" : "Customer",
      "validFor" : null,
      "value" : "Csp"
    }, {
      "active" : true,
      "defaultValue" : false,
      "label" : "Partner",
      "validFor" : null,
      "value" : "Prm"
    } ],
    "polymorphicForeignKey" : false,
    "precision" : 0,
    "queryByDistance" : false,
    "referenceTargetField" : null,
    "referenceTo" : [ ],
    "relationshipName" : null,
    "relationshipOrder" : null,
    "restrictedDelete" : false,
    "restrictedPicklist" : true,
    "scale" : 0,
    "searchPrefilterable" : false,
    "soapType" : "xsd:string",
    "sortable" : true,
    "type" : "picklist",
    "unique" : false,
    "updateable" : false,
    "writeRequiresMasterRead" : false
  }
```